# multiple table row toggle

Tags: javascript, css

I found a script to toggle table rows. How can i edit if i want to have two toggle tables?

Many thanks

```js
$('table').find('tr:gt(0)').hide();


$("button").on("click", function() {
    $('table').find('tr:gt(0)').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>   
</table>


<button>click</button>
```

Comment: $('#table1ID,#table2ID').find('tr:gt(0)').toggle();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign id to tables and use it

Like:

```
$('#table1').find('tr:gt(0)').hide();
$('#table2').find('tr:gt(0)').hide();


$("button").on("click", function() {
    $('#table1').find('tr:gt(0)').toggle();
    $('#table2').find('tr:gt(0)').toggle();
});
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table id="table1">
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>   
</table>
<table id="table2">
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>   
</table>


<button>click</button>
```

If you want 2 different buttons, you can do in same way as you have done for one!

Comment: yes i'm looking for 2 different buttons. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('#table1, #table2').find('tr:gt(0)').hide();


$("button").on("click", function() {
    $('table').find('tr:gt(0)').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table id="table1">
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>   
</table>
   
<table id="table2">
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>   
</table>
<button>click</button>
```